# How to remove autoselection for radiobutton in google script for gmail addon?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-addons

I have created Radiobutton group and first one is coming as auto selected. how can i remove that?

```
var radio = CardService.newSelectionInput()
  .setType(CardService.SelectionInputType.RADIO_BUTTON)
radio.setOnChangeAction(CardService.newAction()
     .setFunctionName("setType")
      .setLoadIndicator(CardService.LoadIndicator.SPINNER))
radio.setFieldName("event_type").setTitle("Select Type")
radio.addItem('item1',1,false);
radio.addItem('item2',2,false);
radio.addItem('item3',3,false);
```

Comment: You could add a 4th option before `item1` that went`radio.addItem('choose an option',1,false);` and have that as the "default"

Comment: Its a good one. but do we have any alternative for this. Instead of adding new one can we make deselect everything?

Comment: After some research I found [this documentation](https://www.sitepoint.com/html-checkbox-radio-button-defaults/) on radio buttons, and part of it says "When a checkbox is unchecked or no radio button is selected, nothing is sent for those fields in the HTTP POST. Unlike other input boxes, there’s no default value — the POSTed field simply doesn’t exist. To make it work correctly, you need to check its existence on the server." So there has to be a default selected.

Comment: the fact that an item is visually selected but nothing is returned in `e.formInput` is really a bad bad behaviour

Answer (score 0):

Since you have set values for all the items to false, it is showing the first item as auto selected.

```
radio.addItem('item1',1,false);
radio.addItem('item2',2,false);
radio.addItem('item3',3,false);
```

If you want to show any of the items as default, you can set one of the values to true,

```
radio.addItem('item2',2,true);
```

However, in both the cases, when you submit the form, it returns the value of the item that you have selected, not the autoselected one.

You can test it like this,

```
var radio = CardService.newSelectionInput()
                       .setType(CardService.SelectionInputType.RADIO_BUTTON)
                       .setFieldName("event_type").setTitle("Select Type")
                       .addItem('item1',1,false)
                       .addItem('item2',2,false)
                       .addItem('item3',3,false);

var button = CardService.newTextButton().setText("Submit")
           .setOnClickAction(CardService.newAction().setFunctionName('test'));



function test(e){
  Logger.log(e.formInputs.event_type);
}
```

The logs shows value of selected radio-button as [1.0] if item1 is selected.